# Using method references

Tags: java, actionlistener, java-8, method-reference

I've got a `JButton`called `saveButton` and want it to call the `save` method when it is clicked. Of course we can do it using the old approach:

```
    saveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            save();
        }
    });
```

But today I want to use new Java 8 features like method references. Why does

```
    saveButton.addActionListener(this::save);
```

not work? How is it done using method references?

Comment: What does `addActionListener` expect as an argument? [Read the tutorial on method references.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)

Comment: Your `save` method does not have the same signature as `actionPerformed`. Therefore it cannot be interpreted as an implementation of the SMI that is `ActionListener`. You need to read more about method references in Java 8.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thanks. I just changed the signature of `save`to `private void save(ActionEvent e)`. Now it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` requires single parameter `e`. If you want to use a method reference, your method must have the same signature.

```
private void myActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    save();
}
```

Then you can use method reference:

```
saveButton.addActionListener(this::myActionPerformed);
```

Or you can use lambda instead (notice `e` parameter):

```
saveButton.addActionListener(e -> save());
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, this isn't a method reference but a lambda - it doesn't actually answer the OP's question...

Comment: You are right. There are two questions `Why does
 not work?` and `How is it done using method references?`. You have answered the second question in comments so I just answered the first one.

Comment: See my alternative answer below

Answer (score 2):

You can use a lambda:

```
saveButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> save());
```

This can be done because the ActionListener is a functional interface (i.e. there is only one method). A functional interface is any interface that contains only one abstract method. Lambdas are shorthand for the call.

Alternatively to using the Lambda you can use a method reference by having your class implement the
interface in question (or some other class with an instance variable). Here is a full example:

```
public class Scratch implements ActionListener {

    static JButton saveButton = new JButton();

    public void save(){};

    public void contrivedExampleMethod() {

        saveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                save();
            }
        });

        // This works regarless of whether or not this class
        // implements ActionListener, LAMBDA VERSION
        saveButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> save());

        // For this to work we must ensure they match
        // hence this can be done, METHOD REFERENCE VERSION
        saveButton.addActionListener(this::actionPerformed);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        save();
    }
}
```

This of course is just a contrived example but it can be done either way assuming you are passing the correct method or creating the correct inner class (like) implementation using Lambdas. I think the lambda way is more efficient in terms of achieving what you want because of the dynamic nature. That is after all why they are there.