# How to use the same actionListener than other element in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, actionlistener, runnable, printwriter

I'm working in a chat app. In this app I have a `JTxtField txtMessage` which sends the message when the user pushes Enter. I want to add a `JButton btn_send` which does the same thing, but if I add `btn_send.addActionListener(enviar_mensaje)` the method does not do anything until I push Enter in the `JTextField`.

How can I use `JTxtField` and `JButton` for the same method?

```
public void write(){
    Thread writeThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
                txtMessage.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                        String sendMessage = txtMessage.getText();
                        writer.println(sendMessage);
                        txtMessage.setText("");
                        chatArea.append("Server say: "+sendMessage+"\n");
                        btnClean.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                                  chatArea.setText("");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }       
        }
    });
    writeThread.start();
}
```

Comment: You're adding an action listener inside an `actionPerformed`? That's not good. Prepare the action listeners before the thread (which I don't know what it's for).

Comment: And hint: the primary language here is **English**. That is also true for code; so instead of directly pasting your source code, consider creating a minimal viable example that uses english terms. Helps a lot with to receive good answers. And: under_bares are a no go in Java names, you **only** use them within SOME_CONSTANT.

Comment: @user1803551 I'll tell you when I do those changes.

Comment: @GhostCat thanks for your advices. I already improved my code :)

Answer (score 1):

The idea of ActionListeners is that they receive some ActionEvent e.

So, when you want to attach the same listener to multiple objects, like in:

```
ActionListener a1 = ... 

button.addActionListener(a1);
textField.addActionListener(a1);
```

then of course, your ActionListener should inspect that *e* in order to understand the context in which it was called.

Then: in case you are using Java8, you can use **method references** in order to provide ActionListeners; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26319537/using-method-references) for a really nice example how to do that!

Comment: It's an interesting answer, I tell you when I submit the changes ;)

Answer (score 0):

I could finally solve the problem that afflicts me, I had to take the methods that were within write() and then call them from ActionListener. Thanks to all!!

```
public void sendMessage(){

    String message = txtMessage.getText();

    writer.println(message);

    txtMessage.setText("");

    chatArea.append("Server says: "+message+"\n");

}


public void clean(){

    chatArea.setText("");

}


public void write(){

Thread message = new Thread(new Runnable(){

    public void run(){

        try{

            writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);



            txtMessage.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                    sendMessage();

                }

            });



            sendBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                    sendMessage();

                }

            });



            cleanBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                    clean();

                }

            });



        }catch(Exception ex){

            ex.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

});

message.start();

}
```